# Stuck at making decision between native app or web app

Tags: ios, web-applications, native

I'm currently graduating at a small company which makes and sells accounting software.

My task during my graduation is to make a Mobile application which supports some functionality of this software. 
For instance: making a report on site and uploading it to the server,logging hours worked, retrieving sales information etc..

I'm currently doing research on which platform I should deploy but I'm getting confused in what shape my application should be made.

I can't make a choice what I should recommend, Web app or Native app?

I need help making a recommendation:

- Security is important. (we deal with confidential information)
- Maintenance is very important. (they will have to support it in the future and have low resources available. (small company))
- Development costs (I have no clue here.)
- User experience (Because this is a business app, is a web app good enough?)
- The business market here is currently very iOS (Apple) saturated (about 80%) but I do need to think of the future. (Android, WP7)

So What do u recommend with the given information, web or native? Do I need more information before making a decision / recommendation if so, what sort of information?

**ps** I think this question belongs on stackoverflow, if not please move it to the appropriate site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what you're looking to accomplish, I'd recommend taking the mobile web app route.  Here's why:

> Security is important. (we deal with confidential information)

You could make a case either way, but I feel that a mobile web app is better for security.  Like Ganzolo said, it can have as much security as a typical web app.  Also, since it doesn't store data on the device itself, you won't have to worry about a data breach in the event of a lost or stolen phone (assuming you're not using HTML5 offline storage).

> Maintenance is very important. (they will have to support it in the future and have low resources available. (small company))

Mobile web apps have an advantage here.  If you built native apps, you'd have to build and maintain separate apps for each platform.  On the other hand, since one mobile web app reaches all platforms, you'd only ever have to maintain one app.  Also, you won't have to update a mobile web app with each OS update, like you would with a native app.  If you want to go one step further, you could even build a mobile web app with separate presentation layers for smartphones, tablet, and PCs ([like this](http://www.mrc-productivity.com/solutions/mobile.html)).  That way, one mobile app would look different (yet native) on any device, but you'd only have to maintain one underlying application.

> Development costs (I have no clue here.)

Depends on how many platforms you want to reach.  If you're building for one platform, the costs are similar.  If you're building for multiple platforms, mobile web apps are far cheaper.  One mobile web app reaches all platforms, whereas you'd have to build a separate native app for each platform.

> User experience (Because this is a business app, is a web app good enough?)

You'll get a better UI with a native app, but a mobile web app should be more than sufficient for most business apps.  Use a good mobile framework (like [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)), and you can build a mobile web app that looks and feels almost native.

> The business market here is currently very iOS (Apple) saturated (about 80%) but I do need to think of the future. (Android, WP7)

Mobile web apps are a much safer choice for the future.  Who knows what the mobile platform landscape will look like in 2 or 3 years?  Maybe WP7 will be popular.  Maybe some new OS will be popular.  It changes so fast, there's no way to know.  The only thing I do know is this: The web will still be popular.  If you build a mobile web app, you insulate yourself from all future mobile OS battles.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion would be to go for a web App :

> • Security is important. (we deal with confidential information)

Sercurity in a web app cannot be worse than security in a regular website (like online banking)

> • Maintenance is very important. (they will have to support it in the
>   future and have low resources available. (small company))

Maintenance is really easy for a web app since you can make updates without going through the process of submitting your app to the store and waiting.

> • Development costs (I have no clue here.)

Development cost will be lower with a web app as you'll have 1 code for every phones (and most of them are using webkit which will be simplier)

> • User experience (Because this is a business app, is a web app good
>   enough?)

It's hard to answer this question without knowing your project but for simple UI it can be good enough

> • The business market here is currently very iOS (Apple) saturated
>   (about 80%) but I do need to think of the future. (Android, WP7)

Yes you need to think about the future that the most important because you can only do simple functionality in web apps. So if future requirement, will have more complex functionality then you'll have to move into native apps.

Hope I've been helpful

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, web apps always tend to be sluggish on the UI front. I would always opt for a native app, if you don't have to support multiple platforms at once (iOS, Android, generic).

- Security: Make your app connections over SSL
- Maintenance: The only problem here is that you may have to wait 7 days for App Store approval for native apps
- Development costs: Depends on who makes the app, shouldn't be too different.
- UX: Defenitely native!
- Multiplatform: As I said, for multi platform a web app is probably best

If you opt for a web app, make sure the user doesn't have the impression of "the app isn't doing anything" while loading stuff.